# Print unicode in windows console

Tags: c++, windows, unicode

I'm trying to print Unicode symbol in console window using c++
here is my code

```
_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
std::wcout  << L"\u2B24";
```

Strange thing is, this code giving correct output for some Unicodes and not (it prints question mark instead of character) for some. I cannot figure-out why. 
as example works for [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/061f/index.htm)(\u061F) and not works for [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2b24/index.htm)(\u2B24)

Any Idea what I'm missing?

**Edit:**

Code:  `std::wcout  << L"Test-"<<L"\u061F"<< L"-Test" << std::endl;`

Output: `Test-?-Test`

Comment: define "works". in particular differentiate between display and storage. can you copy that character back, then it's properly stored.

Comment: @ Cheers and hth. - Alf : Sorry, I didn't get what u mean?

Comment: add some ordinary text before and after \u2B24. output it to console. copy and paste from console to e.g. Windows' "write". or Word. i've checked that "write" can display that character in Windows 8.1, but you can check it by typing 2B24 and pressing Alt X. note that this is in a group that e.g. the Chrome browser doesn't handle well.

Comment: It could of course depend on the font that's configured in the console window. If the font doesn't have the Unicode entry you're referencing, it won't display. You could check this by looking at the console window properties, and verifying using Character Map that the font has that character.

Comment: @icabod: Yes man, You are right. you may post as a answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can depend on the font that's configured to be used by the console window.  If the font being used doesn't have the Unicode entry you're referencing, it won't display it.  You can check which font you're using in the Properties of the command window.  Then open up that font in the Character Map application that MS provide, and you can check which codes are available.

As an aside, you can [add fonts to the Console window](https://superuser.com/q/5035/19224).  However you probably need to bear in mind that someone else running your software may not have the same font configured as you.